# Publishing a Wcf service using BasicHttpBinding for remote clients

Tags: c#, wcf

I've created 3 projects:

**WcfServer** -- The default WCF Service Library project, unchanged.

**WcfServerConsole** -- Console Application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/WcfTest/";

        Type contract = typeof(IService1);
        Type implementation = typeof(Service1);

        var address = baseAddress + implementation.Name;
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var service = new ServiceHost(implementation, new Uri[] { new Uri(address) });

        service.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);
        AddBehaviors(service);
        service.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Server ready.  Press ENTER to terminate.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        service.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private static void AddBehaviors(ServiceHost service)
{
    var smb = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (smb == null)
    {
        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        service.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    }
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

    var sdb = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    if (sdb == null)
    {
        sdb = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
        service.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
    }
    sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
}
```

**WcfClientConsole** -- Console Application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    var proxy = new Service1Client();
    proxy.Open();
    var response = proxy.GetData(42);
    proxy.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Everything works fine locally.  When I run the server, I can see http://localhost:9000/WcfTest/Service1 in my browser, and communication works as expected (run server, run client, see "You entered: 42" in WcfClientConsole).  Now I want to do this remotely.  I change `baseAddress` to `"http://0.0.0.0:9000/WcfTest/"` and run the server on another machine (192.168.150.140).  On that machine, in a browser I can open http://localhost:9000/WcfTest/Service1 and http://127.0.0.1:9000/WcfTest/Service1 and http://192.168.150.140:9000/WcfTest/Service1 no problems.  On my machine, my browser can't connect to http://192.168.150.140:9000/WcfTest/Service1, nor can Add Service Reference, and changing proxy to `new Service1Client("BasicHttpBinding_IService1", "http://192.168.150.140:9000/WcfTest/Service1");` also fails ("There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.150.140:9000/WcfTest/Service1 that could accept the message.").

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you can't connect to that path with a web browser I'd suspect a firewall issue.

Comment: +1 can you telnet to port 9000

Comment: @John Bingo, firewall issue.  For several other projects, Windows prompts me to add a rule when a program/service requires one.  Apparently this is not the case if the project is WCF-based.  TCPView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) tells me the name of the process listening on port 9000 is actually "System", which might have something to do with it.  Much thanks!

Comment: Meet exactly the same problem as yours, how did you solve this problem finally? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your firewall.  That's usually the top cause of this kind of issue.